# Algebra that includes functions and graphing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

The answer to the following is B. Can someone explain me how it is please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find $f(3)$ using the upper left chart. The $f(3)$ corresponding to $x = 3$. So we have $f(3) = 2$

Then using that value, look at the value you obtain for $f(3)$, where $f(x)$ is the new x = 2 value to search for in the chart to the right: we use $x = f(3) = 2$ to find the $g(x)$ corresponding to $x = f(3) = 2$.

Then corresponding g-value to x = 2 will be your needed value, $-3$: $$g(f(3)) = g(2) = -3$$

It's like a mapping $$x \; \implies \; f(x) \;\implies  \;g(f(x))$$ $$3 \;\implies\;\; f(3) = 2 \;\;\implies \;\;g(2) = -3$$

Comment: Does this make sense, Little Jon?

Comment: So thus f should be equal too 2?

Comment: yes, $f(3) = 2$. Then search the left hand column of the second table to find the row containing 2. The g-value corresponding to 2 is $-3$. So $g(f(3)) = g(2) = -3$.

Comment: I understand thanks for the reply.

Comment: You're welcome, Little Jon!

Comment: It 's complete.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have $f(3)$ which is 2. So $g(f(3))=g(2)=-3$

Answer (score 1):

From the table, you have $f(3) = 2$, $g(2) = -3$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

suppose the given a two table $a)$ and $b)$. Look the table $a)$ and have:

$$
if x=3\Rightarrow f(3)=2
$$.

We have find a, $g(f(3))$,i.e. find a $g(2)$ Now look the table $b)$. Finally, $g(2)=-3$